# laravel select box values showing

Tags: php, html, laravel

I made a admin panel with laravel 5.4 . I want to show my category list using category table in products items edit view page. This is my product items edit page controller.

```
  public function edit($id)
    {
        $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

        //$sub_cat = SubCat::all();
        $sub_cat = SubCat::with('category')->get();

        return view('admin.items.edit', compact(['item', 'sub_cat']));
    }
```

And this is my product items edit page view selection box values show

```
  <div class="form-group">
       <label>Main Category</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="main_category" name="main_category">
           @if(!empty($sub_cat))
            @foreach ($sub_cat as $pages)
             <option value="{{ $item->id }}">{{ $pages->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
  </div>
```

I used a model relationship like this

```
public function category(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SubCat');
  }
```

How i show my saved category name with other category names into my selection box.

Comment: first of all, your relationship function seems to be wrong. isn't that should be `$this->belongsTo('App\Category');`

Comment: @Tharaka Dilshan but my category model name is SubCat

Comment: if that's so. this piece of code must be wrong. `$sub_cat = SubCat::with('category')->get();` because you are fetching 'category' with 'category'. because 'category relationship' refer to 'SubCat'.

Comment: pardon me, I'm trying to undestand your code.ok?

Comment: @Tharaka Dilshan how can i remake my code?

Comment: your blade code also seems wrong to me. so i suggest you should re clarify your problem / what you trying to achieve / your particular error or something.

Comment: @Tharaka Dilshan i want to show my category table values into items page select box

Comment: try this $sub_cat = SubCat::all() and in the blade file for each loop you are passing wrong id ($item->id),please pass category id like  ($pages->id)

Comment: @Sunil kumawat when i save category name i used category id. then i want to show category name using category id in my products item view. how can i do it with relationships

Comment: visit the below answer. @KalanaMihiranga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all get all the categories like this

```
 public function edit($id)
        {
            $item = Item::findOrFail($id);

            $sub_cat = SubCat::all(); //get all the categories


            return view('admin.items.edit', compact(['item', 'sub_cat']));
        }
```

in the blade file run loop on $sub_cat collection and **replace $item->id to $pages->id**

```
<div class="form-group">
       <label>Main Category</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="main_category" name="main_category">
           @if(!empty($sub_cat))
            @foreach ($sub_cat as $pages)      //loop on $sub_cat
            <option value="{{ $pages->id }}" {{ $item->category_id == $pages->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }}>{{ $pages->name }}</option>  
            @endforeach
            @endif
        </select>
  </div>
```

Comment: oh its my mistake. your answer is correct. but i want to show my saved category name into select option value

Comment: visit the updated answer @KalanaMihiranga, I added this code {{ $item->category_id == $pages->id ? 'selected="selected"' : '' }} in the option menu

Comment: $item->category_id please check id name in the item table (which you saved in the item table)